buy button doesnt go to my succes/failure form and doesnt decrement my inventory values (HTML,JAVA,SPRINGBOOT)
So i have a mainscreen.html where i have 2 tables, 1 with parts and 1 with products. On my products table i have the name,the price,the inventory and the action on my products. I also got a buy now button, and when i click it i get an whitelabel error page: And it also doesnt decrement my inventory
mainscreen.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>OneStop</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"> <!-- Link your custom CSS file -->
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">OneStop</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
                aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/about">About</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container mt-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <h1 class="heading-primary">Welcome to OneStop</h1>
            <p class="lead">Your one-stop shop for all your inventory needs</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Parts Section -->
    <div class="row mt-5">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2 class="text-center">Parts</h2>
            <a href="/showFormAddInPart" class="btn btn-primary btn-custom btn-block">Add Inhouse Part</a>

            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped mt-3">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Inventory</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr th:each="tempPart : ${parts}">
                    <td th:text="${tempPart.name}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${tempPart.price}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${tempPart.inv}"></td>
                    <td>
                        <a th:href="@{/showPartFormForUpdate(partID=${tempPart.id})}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-3">Update</a>
                        <a th:href="@{/deletepart(partID=${tempPart.id})}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-3"
                           onclick="if(!(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this part?')))return false">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <!-- Products Section -->

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2 class="text-center">Products</h2>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-custom btn-block">Add Product</a>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped mt-3">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Inventory</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr th:each="tempProduct : ${products}">
                    <td th:text="${tempProduct.name}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${tempProduct.price}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${tempProduct.inv}"></td>
                    <td>
                        <a th:href="@{/showProductFormForUpdate(productID=${tempProduct.id})}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-3">Update</a>
                        <a th:href="@{/deleteproduct(productID=${tempProduct.id})}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-3"
                           onclick="if(!(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this product?')))return false">Delete</a>
                        <a th:href="@{/buyPage(productID=${tempProduct.id})}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm mb-3">Buy Now</a>


                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+Knujsl5+CEuTRblB8BEu6vEW+gFgm0q8Ew+8Ew3RM2j5uB"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clearSearch() {
        window.location = "[[@{/}]]";
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>


BuyController.java:
package org.example.controller;

import org.example.domain.Product;
import org.example.repositories.ProductRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import java.util.Optional;

@Controller
public class BuyController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    @PostMapping("/buyPage")
    public String buyProduct(@RequestParam("productId") Long productId) {
        Optional<Product> optionalProduct = productRepository.findById(productId);

        if (optionalProduct.isPresent()) {
            Product product = optionalProduct.get();
            if (product.getInv() > 0) {
                product.setInv(product.getInv() - 1);
                productRepository.save(product);
                return "redirect:/purchaseSuccess";
            } else {
                return "redirect:/purchaseError";
            }
        } else {
            return "redirect:/purchaseError";
        }
    }

    @GetMapping("/purchaseSuccess")
    public String displayPurchaseSuccess() {
        return "purchaseSuccess";
    }

    @GetMapping("/purchaseError")
    public String displayPurchaseError() {
        return "purchaseError";
    }
}


ProductServiceImpl:
package org.example.service;

import org.example.domain.Product;
import org.example.repositories.ProductRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {

    private final ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Autowired
    public ProductServiceImpl(ProductRepository productRepository) {
        this.productRepository = productRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Product> findAll() {
        return (List<Product>) productRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Product findById(Long theId) {
        Optional<Product> result = productRepository.findById((long) theId);
        return result.orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Did not find product with id: " + theId));
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Product theProduct) {
        productRepository.save(theProduct);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteById(int theId) {
        productRepository.deleteById((long) theId);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Product> listAll(String keyword) {
        if (keyword != null) {
            return productRepository.search(keyword);
        }
        return (List<Product>)productRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public boolean buyNow(Long productId) {
        Optional<Product> optionalProduct = productRepository.findById(productId);
        if (optionalProduct.isPresent()) {
            Product product = optionalProduct.get();
            int currentInventory = product.getInv();
            if (currentInventory > 0) {
                product.setInv(currentInventory - 1);
                productRepository.save(product);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false; // Product not found or inventory is already 0
    }
}



does console show any errors? if yes please post them
